# Fetch last Refresh time of Materialized View in CockroachDB

Tags: sql, materialized-views, cockroachdb

In CockroachDB v20.2, one can retrieve a list of [Materialized Views](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v20.2/views#materialized-views) using:

```
> SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_matviews;
  schemaname | matviewname | matviewowner | tablespace | hasindexes | ispopulated | definition
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  public     | VIEWNAME    | root         | NULL       |   false    |    true     | VIEWDEFINITION
```

From here, how can we find when this View was last [Refreshed](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v20.2/refresh)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information isn't available from the internal tables, as far as I know. I don't think PostgreSQL has it either.

A workaround could be to define your materialized view with an additional timestamp column, like:

```
create materialized view my_view as select col, now() as last_updated from tab;
```

The downside of this is that every row in the view will have this column and will use the extra disk space.